# Cant run JApplet on html, ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, html, applet, classnotfoundexception, japplet

I wrote a simple JApplet and I want to run it on my website. I pack it into a .jar file and use applet tag on html. This is my html:

```
<html>
<applet code="main.class" 
codebase="test/"
archive="tmp.jar"
width="600" height="95">
<param name="type" value="hello">
<param name="IP" value="127.0.0.1">
</html>
```

And this is my main.java:

```
public class main extends JApplet{
    public String str, IP;
    public ImagePanel panel;
    protected void loadAppletParameters(){
         String at = getParameter("type");
         str = (at != null) ? at : "world";
         at = getParameter("IP");
         IP = (at != null) ? at : "127.0.0.1";
    }
    public void init(){
        loadAppletParameters();
        System.out.println("hi: ");
        panel = new ImagePanel();
        this.add(panel);

    }

    public class ImagePanel extends JPanel{

        private BufferedImage image;

        public ImagePanel() {
           try {                
              image = ImageIO.read(new File("img.jpg"));
           } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
        }
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);           
        }
        public void change_image(String path){
            try {
                image = ImageIO.read(new File(path));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it caught the ClassNotFoundException when I opened the web file. Please help or give me some advice. Thanks alot.

Comment: Did you check the Java console for detailed error?

Comment: I've checked it, and there is no error.

Comment: Does it not occur to you, that the directory structure & location of the HTML and the `tmp.jar` is important to solving this?  Please [edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23980853/edit) to include that information. BTW - 1) `g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);` should be `g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);` since every `JComponent` **is an** `ImageObserver`. 2) `image = ImageIO.read(new File("img.jpg"));` Resources for applets need to be loaded be `URL`, not `File`.  Preferably an `URL` formed relative to the `codebase` specified in HTML, or the document base.

Answer (score 2):

Try compiling the `.java` file to get the `.class` file and paste it in `test/`. Check if it words.